# How to get all the src and href attributes of a web site

Tags: javascript, image, web, attributes, src

I want a way to get all the src and href attributes(like images and links) in a website. How can i make this in javascript?
I try this:

```
var ilist=document.links;

for(var i = 0; i < ilist.length; i++) {
   if(ilist[i].href) {
       alert(ilist[i].href)
   }
}
```

But for a something, this not works. Only works for . I want all href's and all src's for all tags. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using plain JS you can do:
The string that we give **querySelectorAll** is just a normal CSS selector.

```
var srcNodeList = document.querySelectorAll('[src],[href]');
for (var i = 0; i < srcNodeList.length; ++i) {
  var item = srcNodeList[i];
    if(item.getAttribute('src') !== null){
         alert(item.getAttribute('src'));
    }
    if(item.getAttribute('href') !== null){
         alert(item.getAttribute('href'));
    }
}
```

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vpbepvco/1/

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery you can run each on all elements with the all selector

```
$( "*" ).each(function() {
     $(this).attr("src");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery, but you have to take care about performance.

```
$("[src],[href]").each(function(){
   var $el = $(this);
   if( $el.is("a") ) {
      // do some stuff with A element
   } else if( $el.is("img") ) {
      // do some stuff with A element
   }
 });
```